# Видоизменение слова

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование, глаголы, единственное-множественное-число

Как правильно использовать слово "необходимо" в данном контексте?

1. В дружбе необходимо доверие и общие нравственные ценности.
2. В дружбе необходимы доверие и общие нравственные ценности.

Answer (score 1):

*Доверие* — единственное число, *ценности* — множественное число. Существительные употреблены как однородные члены при одном и том же сказуемом. Поэтому выбираем множественное число:

***В дружбе необходимы доверие и общие нравственные ценности.***

(Продолжим, ибо потребовалось.)

[Согласование сказуемого с подлежащим](https://www.e-reading.club/chapter.php/1015483/236/Rozental_-_Spravochnik_po_pravopisaniyu%2C_proiznosheniyu%2C_literaturnomu_redaktirovaniyu.htm)

**На согласование сказуемого может оказать влияние наличие среди подлежащих формы множественного числа:** *В постель ее уложили ревность и слезы* (Чехов) [у нас ДОВЕРИЕ и ЦЕННОСТИ]. **Но и в этом случае возможна** форма единственного числа сказуемого: *Несся тяжелый топот кованых сапог и крикливые бабьи взвизги* (Серафимович).

Comment: Почему это "поэтому"? Есть масса примеров, где это не так.

Comment: Конечно, есть, сколько угодно. Вы правы, ответы надо формулировать более подробно и доказательно. А посему я приношу свои извинения и дополняю ответ. Всего вам доброго! Бдите!)

Comment: Екатерина, получается,что оба варианта подходят в изначальном примере?

Comment: Да, оба варианта допустимы. Прочитайте статью по ссылке, там есть информация о предстоящем сказуемом и однородных членах при нём. Но в вашем случае из-за формы множественного числа второго однородного члена лучше выбрать множественное число и у сказуемого.